# Objectify OnSave for Id field stopped working after upgrading from v4 to v5

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am populating id just before saving using @OnSave.

```
@OnSave
public void populateId() {
    id = email + " " + module.name();
}
```

It worked fine for Objectify v4, but fails in v5 with error "Cannot save an entity with a null String @Id"

Is this an intentional change or a bug in v5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating @Id or @Parent is not supported in v5. [Dev Docs say](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/LifecycleCallbacks), "Caution: You can't update @Id or @Parent fields in a @OnSave callback"